# What are the disadvantages to Ninja Bridging in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-hypixel-bedwars

Every time I join a game of Minecraft Hypixel, I always see Ninja Bridging. **So, I always wonder, are there any disadvantages to this type of bridging?**

---

For those who don't know what Ninja Bridging is:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its faster I guess if you can pull it off, but its also way easier to fall off into the void. If you hold shift the entire time you wont have that problem.

Comment: True. @Aceplante